# Laravel group admin routes

Tags: php, laravel

Is there a way to cleanly group all routes starting with `admin/`?
I tried something like this, but it didn't work ofcourse:

```
Route::group('admin', function()
{
    Route::get('something', array('uses' => 'mycontroller@index'));
    Route::get('another', array('uses' => 'mycontroller@second'));
    Route::get('foo', array('uses' => 'mycontroller@bar'));
});
```

Corresponding to these routes:

```
admin/something
admin/another
admin/foo
```

I can ofcourse just prefix all those routes directly with `admin/`, but I'd like to know if it's possible to do it *my way*.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately no. Route groups were not designed to work like that. This is taken from the Laravel docs.

> Route groups allow you to attach a set of attributes to a group of routes, allowing you to keep your code neat and tidy.

A route group is used for applying one or more filters to a group of routes. What you're looking for is bundles!

## Introducing Bundles!

Bundles are what you're after, by the looks of things. Create a new bundle called 'admin' in your bundles directory and register it in your application/bundles.php file as something like this:

```
'admin' => array(
    'handles' => 'admin'
)
```

The handles key allows you to change what URI the bundle will respond to. So in this case any calls to **admin** will be run through that bundle. Then in your new bundle create a routes.php file and you can register the handler using the **(:bundle)** placeholder.

```
// Inside your bundles routes.php file.
Route::get('(:bundle)', function()
{
    return 'This is the admin home page.';
});

Route::get('(:bundle)/users', function()
{
    return 'This responds to yoursite.com/admin/users';
});
```

Hope that gives you some ideas.

Comment: Thanks! Didn't think about bundles.

Comment: still no work around this issue, but with Bundles? I'm asking for Laravel 3

Answer (score 3):

In `Laravel 4` you can now use `prefix`:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin'], function() {

    Route::get('something', 'mycontroller@index');

    Route::get('another', function() {
        return 'Another routing';
    });

    Route::get('foo', function() {
        return Response::make('BARRRRR', 200);
    });

    Route::get('bazz', function() {
        return View::make('bazztemplate');
    });

});
```