# How to associate a route to a package?

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing

Can i do something like Symfony to associate a route to a package? 
So every route on my routes.php admin package are prefixed with '/admin/'?

Because actually i can put a route on my main routes.php like '/admin' and i can put the same on my package routes without knowing that on my main routes this route is already in use.

My current package routes.php is something like this:

```
Route::get('/admin', 'MyVendor\administration\AdminController@test');
```

But what happens if i put the same '/admin' on the main routes? i dont like this approach.

Sorry for my English, i hope you understand me.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can (from laravel site)

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'admin'), function()
{
    Route::get('user', function()
    {
        //
    });
});
```

Read the documentation about [Route Prefixing](http://laravel.com/docs/routing#route-prefixing) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12479402/laravel-group-admin-routes) too.